# Create and log in to a web site with http POST request without using HttpUrlConnection library or other libraries

Tags: java, post, logging, request, httpurlconnection

I am trying to create a http post request without using any library such as java.net.HttpUrlConnection, java.net.URLConnection, URL.openConnection() etc in Java. But every example on the internet has used libraries such as HttpUrlConnection. Can anyone please help me to create a Post request for login in a web site in java?

Comment: What's the problem with this library? I'm pretty sure every other lib would be wrapping this internally as nobody wants to implement reading & parsing bytestreams of TCP/IP connections. Are you sure you really want to do that?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow! You might want to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [read the on-topic page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and the [How-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For your question, a simple google search yielded [this result](https://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-login-form-in-servlet)

Comment: Hi @Zilvinas, This is a project and we must don't use HttpUrlConnection. I know this is a very usefull library. But We need to create our request from scratch.

Comment: Hi @Turing85, I hope you winn a Turing award too! JFYI, I searched so much but in your mentioned link, this has used servlet library. I do not want to use any library.

Comment: How about Spring `RestTemplate`? https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use low level networking working directly with [`java.net.Socket`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) objects. Perhaps the best place to start is the [Java sockets tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html), and then check out the sample echo client therein. That will show you how to connect to a server and then read and write data to/from it.

In order to construct the required messages you also need to understand [HTTP POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)). The topic is far too detailed to discuss here, so you will need to some reading.

Here is a program that sends a simple hard-coded POST request to a server running on localhost:1234:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class SendPost {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String post_request = "POST /login HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:1234\r\nContent-Length: 41\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\nusername=bob%40test.com&password=i+forget";

            Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());           
            out.writeBytes(post_request);          
            s.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This just sends a POST request containing a user name and a password using the same format that your browser would if you were using it to submit a login form.

The (heavily simplified) request looks like this:

```
POST /login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1234
Content-Length: 41
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

username=bob%40test.com&password=i+forget
```

Comment: This is a very good example which I think I can use for my first try after reading HTTP POST request structure. Can you please let me know what is the exactly your username and password values?  I see nusername=bob%40test.com&password=i+forget", but is your username is bob%40test.com or just bob? Excuse me, but as I wanna have a test on my login page, I need to know what is the exact format of using username and password in my request.

Comment: User name is `bob@test.com`, password is `i forget`. These illustrate that it's not always straightforward when dealing with HTTP. Each of these values has been "url encoded" (AKA [percent encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)) such that non-ascii characters, or other characters that might have special meaning, are percent encoded to avoid misinterpretation. In this case `@` has been replaced by `%40` and the space by `+`.

Comment: Thank you, so how can I find which characters should I use in my parameters instead of &? My password and user name have not any space, but I think between username and password, I need to use &.

Comment: I used your example, and I got UnknownHostException. I wanna to login to this web site: http://elsrv2.cs.umass.edu/accounts/login/?next=/fakebook/
Can you please check my login form and let me know how many and which parameters I need to post in my post request? I am using this request :String post_request = "POST HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:http://elsrv2.cs.umass.edu/accounts/login/?next=/fakebook/:8080\r\nContent-Length: 41\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\nusername=1111&password=222&csrfmiddlewaretoken=TLa4KsHW8T18FTJxn1zJZzsypLDrULgZ";

Comment: @ShahroozPooryousef: you're going to have to do some reading, the topics that you ask about are far too broad to discuss here.

Comment: @ShahroozPooryousef: regarding the unknown host problem, set the `Host` header properly, to `Host: elsrv2.cs.umass.edu`, `Content-Length` needs to be set to the length of POST body, you need to post it to the correct URL, i.e. `POST /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1`.

Comment: Thank you @mhawke I will have a try now.